# Questions regarding the Construction/Meaning of the Algebraic Cotangent Space

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry

I've been studying smooth manifolds in order to learn more about differential geometry. Recently I ran into a construction of the cotangent space that I hadn't seen much before. In many resources that I have used, the tangent space is created first and then the cotangent is defined as its dual. However, I have also seen it defined like the Zariski tangent space using alebraic rather than differential techniques. My question is about the motivations behind this construction.

As I understand it, we first consider the ring of $C^r$ functions $M\to \mathbb{R}$ and look at the ideal $I_p$ of functions vanishing at a point $p$. That is,

$$I_p = \bigg\{f\in C^r(M) : f(p)=0\bigg\}$$

My first question is related to this ideal. Specifically, how would one be lead to consider this ideal? I have worked out that this ideal is the kernel of a ring homomorphism sending each function to its value at $p$, and I have read that all maximal ideas in this ring have this form. I've seen the tangent space motivated through partial derivatives, curves on the manifold, and derivations. Is there a starting point for wanting to consider functions that vanish at $p$?

Next, we can take the square of this ideal $J_p=I_p^2 = \big\{ \sum_{i=1}^nf_ig_i:n\in\mathbb{N}\text{ and all }f_i, g_i\in I_p \big\}$. This is another ideal in the ring. Therefore, there should be a ring homomorphism with kernel $J$. I have not been able to construct this homomorphism, could I have some help getting to it? On top of this, I am wondering why one would want to consider this subset of the larger ideal. That is why is the square of $I$ relevant to the construction of the space?

To complete the construction, the cotangent space is defined as the quotient $I_p/J_p$. Because both $I_p$ and $J_p$ are rngs, can I consider this to be a quotient ring, as $J_p$ must be an ideal of $I_p$ when it is considered a a rng separate from the larger ring? Furthermore,I don't know what the equivalent classes of this ring would be because I do not have a good handle on $J$. For example, is there an example of a function that is in $I_p^2$ that is not in $I_p$? Grasping the difference between $I_p$ and $J_p$ could be helpful.

Many thanks in advance. I hope that someone can help to make this construction a bit clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of motivating and building intuition for this process is looking at things concretely using charts.

Let $h\in J_p$. by definition, $h=fg$ for some $f,g\in I_p$. Using a chart $x^1,\dots,x^n$ containing $p$, we note that $h$ has vanishing first derivative at $p$.
$$
\partial_i h(p)=\partial_i(fg)(p)=g(p)\partial_if(p)+f(p)\partial_ig(p)=0
$$
It's easy to verify that this property is independent of the choice of chart. This states that every element of $J_p$ vanishes at $p$ and has (in an intrinsic sense) vanishing first derivative at $p$. The converse of this statement is tricky; in $r\ge 2$ it is true, and follows from Taylor's theorem. In any case, we can think of $J_p$ in this way.

The quotient $I_p/J_p$ can then be thought of as generated by the equivalence $f\sim g$ if $f-g\in J_p$, that is, the quotient consists of equivalence classes of functions which "agree up to linear order".

These equivalence classes are canonically isomorphic to $T^*M$, Given an equivalence class $[f]$ in the above construction with representative $f$, and a tangent vector (derivation) $v$ at $p$, we can define $[f](v)=v(f)$. This construction is independent of representative. We can also define the differential at $p$ of a $C^r$ function by $d_pf=[f-f(p)]$, and show it agrees with the more common definition of $d_p$.

Comment: That makes a bit more sense. So if I understand correctly, $J_p$ is significant because it is the kernel of the derivative map $I_p\to \mathbb{R}^n$ taking each function in $I_p$ to its derivative at $p$. Therefore, the equivalence classes correspond to different values of this derivative, right?

Do you have a source that proves the converse? If I understand it correctly, we would need to prove that if some function $h$ vanishes at $p$ with vanishing derivative, then it is contained in $J_p$, correct?

Comment: However, as another note  $Jp$ is an ideal with respect to $C^r(M)$ as well. So if we wanted to group functions according to their derivatives at $p$ we could use the equivalence classes in either $C^r(M)/J_p$ or in $I_p/J_p$, right? 

If I am making sense of the construction correctly, we restrict our attention to $I_p$ because the value of the functions at $p$ itself do not matter when we consider the derivative. One way of getting rid of this extraneous information is to look at those which vanish at $p$ because any function can be taken to this ideal via subtraction of $f(p)$, yeah?

Comment: To your first point, we want to _define_ the differential at $p$ as an operator whose kernel is $J_p$, motivated by the fact that all the coordinate differentials at $p$ have the same kernel. To your second point, we need a little bit more than $C^rM/J_p$, since we want to be able to differentiate functions which to not vanish at $p$, e.g. we want $[f]=[f+c]$ for $c\in\mathbb{R}$. The correct quotient would be $(C^rM/\mathbb{R})/J_p$, where the second quotient is understood by noting each class in $C^rM/\mathbb{R}$ has a unique representative in $I_p$.

Comment: To the point about the converse, it suffices to show any $C^1$ function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ with $f(0)=\partial_i f(0)=0$ can be written as a product of $C^1$ functions vanishing at zero. To do this, we note $f$ can be expanded about zero as $$f(x)=f(0)+x^i\int_0^1(\partial_i f)(tx)dt$$ One can verify that both factors in the second term are $C^1$ and vanish at zero.