# Showing that $I/I^2 \simeq T_{x_0}^{\ast} X.$

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-algebras, poisson-geometry, germs, co-tangent-space

> Let $X$ be a Poisson manifold with Poisson bivector field $\Pi.$ Let $x_{0} \in X$ be such that $\Pi (x_{0}) = 0.$ Let $\mathcal O (X)_{x_{0}}$ denote the ring of germs of the smooth functions on $X$ at $x_{0}.$ Consider the maximal ideal $I$ of $\mathcal {O}_{x_{0}}$ consisting of functions vanishing at $x_{0}.$ Consider the Poisson bracket $$\{\cdot, \cdot \} : \mathcal {O}_{x_{0}} \otimes \mathcal {O}_{x_{0}} \longrightarrow \mathcal {O}_{x_{0}}$$ defined by  $f \otimes g \mapsto \Pi (df, dg).$ Since $\Pi (x_{0}) = p$ it follows that $\{\cdot, \cdot \} : \mathcal {O}_{x_{0}} \otimes \mathcal {O}_{x_{0}} \longrightarrow I$ and hence we have a Lie bracket $\{\cdot, \cdot \} : I \otimes I \longrightarrow I.$ Moreover if $f \in I$ and $g \in I^{2}$ we have $\{f, g \} = \Pi(df, dg) \in I^{2}$ so that $I^{2}$ is a Lie ideal of $I.$ This induces a Lie algebra structure on the quotient $I/I^{2} \simeq T_{x_{0}}^{\ast} X$ (the cotangent space of $X$ at $x_{0}$).

My question is $:$ How do we have $I/I^{2} \simeq T_{x_{0}}^{\ast} X\ $? Any suggestion in this regard would be warmly appreciated.

Thanks for your time.

**Source** $:$ Lecture notes on quantum groups by Pavel Etingof (Lecture $2$, Page no. $16$).

Comment: In algebraic geometry, I have seen this done by describing the tangent space in terms of derivations, and then showing these spaces are isomorphic directly by associating derivations to elements of $I/I^2$. Without knowing anything about Poisson geometry, I would try this.

Comment: @A.ThomasYerger$:$ Although I am not familiar with algebraic geometry it might be helpful to get some intuition.  Could you please share the ideas? Thanks.

Comment: ...in my mind this is the *definition* of cotangent bundle.

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3415740/788724) should be helpful